# Validate do laravel retornando resposta errada

Tags: php, laravel, validator

Tenho uma verificação de 2 `uploads` em um formulário com o `validate` na seguinte função:

```
public static function validarComprovantes($request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'pagamento' => 'required|mimes:pdf,jpg,png,jpeg,doc|file|size:max:20000',
        'sentenca' => 'required|mimes:pdf,jpg,png,jpeg,doc|file|size:max:20000',
    ],[
        'pagamento.required' => 'Você deve inserir o comprovamente de pagamento',
        'pagamento.mimes' => ' Você deve inserir um documento nos seguintes formatos: pdf,jpg,png,jpeg,doc',
        'pagamento.uploaded' => 'O arquivo de pagamento deve possuir no máximo 20MB',
        'sentenca.required' => 'Você deve inserir a sentença da causa',
        'sentenca.mimes' => ' Você deve inserir um documento nos seguintes formatos: pdf,jpg,png,jpeg,doc',
        'sentenca.uploaded' => 'O arquivo da sentença deve possuir no máximo 20MB',
    ]);
}
```

Acontece o seguinte quando coloco o pagamento acima de ***20MB*** e a sentença dentro do permitido é me retornado o seguinte erro com a primeira configuração certa, porem retorna a sentença desconfigurada e os mimes que no caso eu coloco(`jpg)`.

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando faço o contrario ele retorna o erro de forma contraria, alguém saberia o motivo da validação estar retornando automaticamente o outro erro?

Comment: Amigo, eu não entendi exatamente o seu erro ainda. Você poderia explicar de uma outra forma para que eu consiga te ajudar.

Comment: Vitor, eu usei validações separadas no final. O validate estava dando erro em validar dois files, sendo um valido e outro não..ele retornava erro para os dois

Answer (score 0):

De acordo ao Laravel pela documentação segue exemplo que o Laravel da:

```
 public static function validarComprovantes($request)
    {

$messages = [
                'pagamento.required' => 'Você deve inserir o comprovamente de pagamento',
                'pagamento.mimes' => ' Você deve inserir um documento nos seguintes formatos: pdf,jpg,png,jpeg,doc',
                'pagamento.uploaded' => 'O arquivo de pagamento deve possuir no máximo 20MB',
                'sentenca.required' => 'Você deve inserir a sentença da causa',
                'sentenca.mimes' => ' Você deve inserir um documento nos seguintes formatos: pdf,jpg,png,jpeg,doc',
                'sentenca.uploaded' => 'O arquivo da sentença deve possuir no máximo 20MB',
    ];

$roles = [
            'pagamento' => 'required|mimes:pdf,jpg,png,jpeg,doc|file|size:max:20000',
            'sentenca' => 'required|mimes:pdf,jpg,png,jpeg,doc|file|size:max:20000',
        ];

   $validation =  Validator::make($request, $roles, $messages);
    }
```

Referência: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-error-messages

Comment: O segundo array são as mensagens de erro referente ao parâmetros que foram inseridos no primeiro array do método `validate`.

Comment: Oque tu colocou ja acusa erro, uma vez que o segundo é a resposta para cada validação do primeiro

Comment: @BetiniO.Heleno você ta customizando errado eu creio vou dar uma olhada com mais calma e atualizarei minha resposta pra te ajudar.

Comment: Agradeço, estou a tentar buscar uma solução, pois era de fato para ele retornar apenas a validação errada.

Comment: Achei o problema vou editar a resposta um momento

Comment: Estou no aguardo, obrigado

Comment: Espero ter te ajudado, com essa dúvida mas de acordo um dos jeitos de fazer um custom é dessa forma mas na documentação tem como usar parametros "custom" =>, como eu não uso muito custom messages do Laravel então é algo pra mim bem vago

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96874/discussion-between-lucas-antonio-and-betini-o-heleno).

Comment: infelizmente, não pegou..

Comment: Qual erro está dando?

Comment: Você ta usando Laravel pt-br?

Comment: O laravel só valida pelo que entendi os tipos dos inputs, mas da uma olhada nisso: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36265166/laravel-how-to-make-custom-validator

Comment: Algum desses links pode te ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45007905/custom-message-laravel-validation